# Capturing advice execution (advising advice) in AspectJ

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to capture the execution of an advice using annotation in Maven, but it says that advice has not been applied. Here is the code:

```
package testMaven8;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;


@Aspect
public class aspecter {

    public static int a;

    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    @Before("execution(*  testMaven8.das.qwe(..))")
    public void testBefore2(){
        System.out.println("yoo2");
        setA(102);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    @Before("execution (* testMaven8.aspecter.testBefore2(..))")
    public void advice1(){
        System.out.println("advicing advice testBefore2");
    }

}
```

Is there something wrong with the code? I'm trying to avoid the usage of Aspect class if it's possible. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advice execution is something special in AspectJ, not a normal method execution. Thus, if you want to capture advice execution you also need a special pointcut with the surprising name - `adviceexecution()` ;-)

Here is some sample code:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Application().doSomething();
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Doing something");
    }
}
```

**Aspect capturing method executions:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class MethodInterceptor {
    @Before("execution(!static * *(..))")
    public void interceptMethod(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

**Aspect capturing advice executions:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class AdviceInterceptor {
    @Before("!within(AdviceInterceptor) && adviceexecution()")
    public void interceptAdvice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

Please do not try to pack the advice execution interceptor into the same aspect as another advice because you can easily end up in an endless recursion if you cannot exclude the `adviceexecution()` pointcut from capturing itself via `!within(AdviceInterceptor)`.

**Console log:**

```
adviceexecution(void de.scrum_master.aspect.MethodInterceptor.interceptMethod(JoinPoint))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
Doing something
```

Comment: As I understand from your code, the capturing advice execution's code will capture any advice executed in the system. Could we specify which advice that we want to capture, just like in normal Aspect class?

Comment: I recommend to read the AspectJ documentation. The answer is no, if you have multiple advices in one aspect, but you can narrow it down easily to all advices in one aspect with `within(MyAspect)` and within the capturing advice filter by signature, see the log above. Is that enough for you as a starting point or do you need an example?

Comment: Another additional question: Is it possible for capturing a specific advice instead of whole advices? as far as i can tell your code will capture any advice executed.

Comment: I already answered that question above: You can filter by signature during runtime. Let me know if you need more sample code, but it is really straightforward. Please note that doing reflection during runtime is slower than refactoring your aspect into several aspects in which to capture a single advice each. But it is your choice.